# EPUB reader/viewer in PHP

Tags: php, html, cakephp, symfony, epub

Is there any module/script available which reads/views EPUB files in a web browser?

If it's available in any PHP framework like Symphony, CakePHP or any other it would be of great help.

Comment: epub are just zipped html files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Epub.js is a javascript library for rendering ePub's in the browser, across many devices. 
https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/
It's very easy to use epub.js with php. I wrote a module to integrate it with Drupal https://drupal.org/project/epub.

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/oplsepublibrary/ does a good job of importing epub files with spine info and one of the examples will let you upload an epub which it later renders.

Answer (score 1):

The EPUB format is a zip archive containing HTML, CSS and images. You could unzip the files and then they are all just viewable in a browser, although you would need to do the work of an Ebook reader when it comes to linking the "chunks" together.

You could use [PHP Zip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) to unzip the EPUB on the server.

Additional warning: there is massive potential to abuse your website if you unzip any old EPUB book. Malicious code in the EPUB could expose you to click-jacking attacks, cross-size scripting attacks, HTML injection attacks and plain old "I've got some code on your server" attacks if someone put files in there with a PHP extension, for example. So you would need to be pretty certain about what you are unzipping.